# How to link to a webpage that is in the same folder and level

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, hyperlink

I am having trouble with accessing a html page that is in the same folder directory and level. Every thing I tried results in a error on the page. I have tried a few ways to navigate to the page, but all fail except for main 5 it just opens the login page again so that does not work either. 
I am a bit lost on how this works. I have attached a picture of now my structure is set up below. 
I am trying to get from home.html to main.html
I am running Spring framework.

[image]

And this is the code that I am using to as the link.

```
 {{>partials/header}}
 <h2>Login Page</h2>
 <h4>Links</h4>

 <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
 <li role="presentation">
    <a href="main">Main 1 </a>
    <a href="/main">Main 2</a>
    <a href="~/main">Main 3</a>
    <a href="../main">Main 4</a>
     <a href=".main">Main 5</a>
 </li>
 </ul>

 {{>partials/footer}}
```

Here is my controller

```
 //New login page
@RequestMapping(value = HOME_URL_MAPPING)
public String inventory(final Model model) {
    return controllerHelper.createUrl(INVENTORY, WebGlobals.HOME);
}

//new page Was the home page before
@RequestMapping(value ="/main")
public String inventgus(final Model model) {
    UserDetails activeUser = (UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    model.addAttribute(CAN_MAKE_REQUEST, canMakeRequest(activeUser));
    model.addAttribute(CAN_APPROVE_REQUEST, canApproveRequest(activeUser));

    return controllerHelper.createUrl(INVENTORY, "main");
}
```

Comment: This will depend on which framework and environment you're running in. Would you mind adding those details?

Comment: Good point I am using spring right now as the frame work.

Comment: are you using any controllers or the like?

Comment: Yes and mustache too.

Comment: What does your controller look like? Specifically how are your routes setup?

Comment: @MNM, while working with spring framework you must be more concerned about the controllers and view resolvers. Please verify that first.

Comment: I added the controller

Answer (score 1):

You were so close! Here's the answer:

```
<a href="./main.html">Main</a>
```

The single dot refers to the current folder and putting a slash means that the file is under that folder.

Comment: Yeah. I just saw your comment that this is using Spring. My bad.  

I've not used Spring, but I've used other MVC's. What's your route to main.html look like?

Comment: I added my controller above. Your answer is right just not what I am doing. I not use to spring either.

Comment: What's the name of your project? The examples I'm looking at seem to find that important.

Comment: dimare-crm is the name

Comment: Try '/dimare-crm/main'. I *think* that's what it should be after skimming some documentation.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
<a href="main.html">Main</a>
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. It may be due to my set up using spring